# Vue class component AddEventListener and RemoveEventListener usage

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, addeventlistener, vue-class-components, removeeventlistener

I want to implement draggable line using `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` events.

In my first attempt I was trying to use arrow-functions-class-properties: https://codesandbox.io/s/example-1-15psm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

But the property `position` in `Test.vue` seems to be non-reactive. Not sure, but my guess is it's because of [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) Vue restriction:

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as `created: () => console.log(this.a)` or `vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod())`. Since an arrow function doesn’t have a `this`, `this` will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through parent scopes until found, often resulting in errors such as Uncaught `TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined` or `Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function`.

In my second attempt I've tryed to use standart class methods:
https://codesandbox.io/s/example-2-t7beu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

It works, except since binded functions `onMouseMove` and `onMouseUp` in `Test.vue` are anonymous I can't unbind them with `removeEventListener`.

So, what's the proper way of using `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` in Vue class components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've overengineered my code.
There is no need to use `arrow-functions-class-properties`, or defining context by using `method.bind(this)`. The following code should work:

```js
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Test extends Vue {
  position = 0;

  onMouseMove(e) {
    let position = this.position;
    position += e.movementY;
    this.position = position;
    console.log("onMouseMove", this.position);
  }

  onMouseUp() {
    console.log("onMouseUp", this.position);
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp);
  }

  onMouseDown() {
    console.log("onMouseDown", this.position);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp);
  }
}
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/example-2-t7beu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark